# Creating 10min periods from time column for each class separately in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, period

I need to create periods and named them like 0,1,2,3 according to time column, for each class in dataframe separately

I have already tried

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']))
newdf = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10Min'),as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['assetId'])
df['period'] = newdf.index.get_level_values(0)
```

But;
This code grouping time but I have same time values in different classes that is why its mixing classes. I want to do it for each class separately. My datafame looks like:

```
Class  Time
702  2018-09-03T04:08:04Z
702  2018-09-03T04:18:34Z
703  2018-09-03T04:08:04Z
703  2018-09-03T04:40:05Z
703  2018-09-03T04:40:05Z
```

The result I need to get is;

```
Class  Time                Period
702  2018-09-03T04:08:04Z    1
702  2018-09-03T04:18:34Z    2
703  2018-09-03T04:08:04Z    1
703  2018-09-03T04:40:05Z    2
703  2018-09-03T04:40:05Z    3
```

Comment: Share a sample of your dataframe please not an image

Comment: Ok. I edited my post.